# C++ app automation on multiple platforms

Tags: automated-testing, java, test-automation-framework, windows, desktop-application

Need to automate **C++ application** testing on Web, Mobile (iOS, Android) and **Desktop (Windows, OSX and maybe Linux)**. Searching for **open source tools only** and automated tests will be written using **Java**. The web is good to go with Selenium WebDriver, Mobile with Appium and Desktop Windows with Winium.Desktop. Does anybody know what tool can be used for **Desktop C++ app automation on Windows, OSX and maybe Linux**?

Comment: Does the application use a UI framework?  Generic, cross-platform GUI automation is a tough one . . . if you only need command line, STAF/STAX works really well.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows I recommend [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/)
You can either record interaction with UI elements or directly write automation scripts with their Basic-like scripting language.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [sikulix](http://sikulix.com/).  It uses computer vision to recognize images on a screen.  It finds images you save and then calculates the coordinates of the image on the screen to interact with it.

It is written in Java and has windows, linux and mac distributions.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using LDTP cobra. which is robust and reliable.
You can also try python (PywinAuto.class), both are open source.

https://github.com/ldtp/cobra